# Request not mapping to controller method

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Hi im trying to figure out why my button within my jsp page is not mapping to the controller method. When i click on the button it shows 404 not available.

Heres the jsp link-

```
<a href="/aucConfirm/${newAuction.idauction}/start" >Start Auction</a>
```

This controller method adds an auction item to "newAuction" -

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/aucConfirm/{idauction}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String confirmAuction(@PathVariable(value = "idauction") int idauction, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        AuctionItem addAuction = (AuctionItem) aucRepository.findOne(idauction);
        model.addAttribute("newAuction", addAuction);
        model.addAttribute("startAction", addAuction.getIdauction() + "/start");
        return "aucConfirm";
    }
```

This is the controller method that the link should map to -

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/aucConfirm/{idauction}/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String startAuction(@PathVariable(value = "idauction") int idauction, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        AuctionItem addAuction = (AuctionItem) aucRepository.findOne(idauction);

        List<Image> imageList = (List<Image>) imageRepository.findByidauction(idauction);
        addAuction.setMainImage(imageList.get(0).getImagepath());
        addAuction.setActive(true);
        aucRepository.save(addAuction);
        return "listing";

    }
```

The link appears to be working fine, the idauction gets populated in the web browser, it just doesnt seem to be mapping to the controller.

This is the full html output:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="/AuctionWebsite/resources/css/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Confirm</title>
    </head>
    <body id="product">
        <header>






<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-    target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-size: 40px " href="/AuctionWebsite/">NoBid</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/AuctionWebsite/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/AuctionWebsite/sell">Sell</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Category <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home & Gardens</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Toys & Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports & Leisure</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for an auction">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">



            <li><a href="/AuctionWebsite/login">Log out</a></li>


  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

        </header>   
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pb-center-column-inner">
                <h1>fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</h1>
                <hr style="margin-top: 8px;">
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: -10px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-6 col-md-6"><h4>Auction ID: 55</h4></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="text-align: right;"><h4>Seller: hazardaguess</h4></div>
                </div>
                <div class="center" style="text-align: left;">
                    <div id="short_description_block">
                        <h4>Details:</h4>
                        <table class="table-data-sheet">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Item condition</td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 12px">New</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 3px">End Time</td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 12px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 3px">Minimum Price</td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 12px">£0.0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 3px">Category</td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 12px">Electronics</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 3px">Returns</td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 12px">You can return</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 3px">Description</td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 12px">f</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-12" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 10px">
                            <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" action="../aucConfirm/uploadFile/55" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="944c58d1-33b3-425c-bd20-154b8a138058" />
</div></form>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
                                <a href="/aucConfirm/55/start" >Start Auction</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="border: 2px solid #FFD700"><a href="/aucConfirm/55/edit">Edit</a></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="border: 2px solid #f44336;"><a href="/aucConfirm/55/cancel">Cancel</a></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


        <script src="/AuctionWebsite/resources/js/dropzone.js"/></script>
            <script>
                Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
                    maxFilesize: 4,
                    parallelUploads: 5,
                    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have u tried looking at the HTML generated from your jsp? Can u add it in your question? Especially the link

Comment: @checklist Full html added, the button link is towards the end

Answer (score 0):

You are already suffixing the `/start` in your `confirmAuction` controller method, you need to remove it from JSP `href`, which is shown below:

```
<a href="/aucConfirm/${newAuction.idauction}" >Start Auction</a>
```

Comment: thanks, but thats not actually linking to anything, was just using it to try and figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being very simple, added the two dots in at the start of the path and it directs correctly now. Thanks for all the responses anyway.

```
<a href="../aucConfirm/${newAuction.idauction}/start" >Start Auction</a>
```